# Media player classic starts at boot up CPU 100% not listed in msconfig. What is going on?

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage, process-explorer, media-player-classic

Every time I boot windows, media player classic starts running in the background (no actual MPC window opens) and hogs the CPU at 100% until I kill it. In process explorer the parent is explorer. I was wondering what could be causing this as I cannot find it under startup  in msconfig.

Versions:

Windows 7 64bit
Windows Media Player Classic x64 - 1.6.1.4235

Comment: make an update to Media Player Classic Home Cinema 1.6.7.7114 and if this doesn't fix it, capture a xperf trace and upload the zipped ETL file: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140264

Comment: use Autoruns from sysinternals to determine how the process is being started. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: @FrankThomas It is not listed! I do not see it anywhere... The interesting thing is that I have completely uninstalled mpc deleted the program folder and it still runs at startup!

Comment: @magicandre1981 So I completely removed the program and rebooted, and it still runs at startup! The path is not the same path, it is running under flash player \AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\SpeedCache\

Comment: I think this would now quality as a duplicate of [A malicious threat was detected in Media Player Classic exe file](http://superuser.com/questions/598323/a-malicious-threat-was-detected-in-media-player-classic-exe-file), since it wasn't Media Player Classic, but a virus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I can't post comments, but have you tried deleting the mpc executable from \AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\SpeedCache\?

If the file runs in the cache of Flashplayer, you can also try to clean that cache with [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)

You can also try to install it again, and then Uninstall with an uninstaller tool like [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html). It will scan your computer after uninstall for any leftovers of the program so you can delete them.

---

You can also search for more startup locations with [Startup CPL](http://www.mlin.net/StartupCPL.shtml). Hopefully you can see your mpc.exe listed somewhere.

Comment: I think you can't comment because there is a minimum of 50 reputation. Yes I removed it and now I get the "windows cannot find..." error at startup. I am trying to figure out what is issuing that command but cant find it in the startup list

Comment: Hmm.. This tool displays startup items from several locations: [startup CPL](http://www.mlin.net/StartupCPL.shtml). Hopefully it will find your mpc startup registry. If not I recommend you to install it again and try Revo Uninstaller (see above). With that you can make sure all leftovers from the program are removed from your system.

Comment: If you want, you can also try to search for mpchc64.exe in the register itself. Type regedit.exe in the start or run menu and open the registry editor. Press ctrl+F and search for mpchc64.

If it finds anything, check if the key name you are browsing ends with "\Run". These are locations that specificy which programs run at boot. If you find an mpchc64 entry in a "\Run key, delete it. Make sure to create a backup of your registry if all this is new for you.

Comment: The startup tool looked promising, but I do not see any reference to MPC anywhere... I had already tried to first uninstall using revo and then searched the registry for any mention of mpc and there was nothing. Thats what's crazy about it, after uninstalling fully, it was still running at startup from the flash player folder mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hmm that's crazy indeed :) I'm running a bit out of options now. You have deleted flash player cache with ccleaner, right?

What you can try is to create a new user account. Then login with that one and see if it gives the error message. If it doesn't, then you can use that account instead. That is better than reinstalling windows for such a weird issue.

If anyone else know something you can try, they are welcome to give some input here.

Comment: I am surprised no more input has come.... I would rather not create a new user account, if anything I will create a blank batch file by the same name just so that the error doesnt come up... but I really wanted to figure out what is running that command at startup, its very frustrating!!

Comment: Oh and another thing, I could not find anything specific in ccleaner referring to clearing flash cache, where exactly is it?

Comment: I found it, I looked with the startup tool again (thanks!) and I found it was being run via a batch file, that is why it was hard to find ! It's pretty weird, I am continuing this as another question here: http://superuser.com/questions/598218/i-would-like-to-understand-why-a-batch-file-appeared-in-flash-player-folder-for

Comment: If you would like to edit your answer in a form that answers my question (i.e. tell me about the startup program) I will accept it as an answer!

Comment: Ok, wonderful. Glad you've found it ;) I will edit my answer so it contains the Startup CPL program :)

One thing is odd, did the Startup CPL found more entries than sysinternals Autoruns? That's weird lol that thing should list everything :)

Comment: I think what was good about startup CPL was that there were not as many entries but the entry I needed to find was there. So it actually made it easier to spot. I am sure I could find it in sysinternals Autoruns but there were so many entries I wasn't able to spot it.

Comment: Ok cool. Sometimes [less is more](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/less_is_more) isn't it? :)

Comment: no doubt... you should be able to comment now :D

Comment: Thx @IsopycnalOscillation :)

Answer (score 1):

Delete all files in `C:\Users\(UserName)\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\SpeedCache`.

Remove the `SpeedUpSystem` registry entry from: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.