# A malicious threat was detected in Media Player Classic exe file

Tags: trojan, media-player-classic

When I run HitmanPro, it says that mpchc64.exe is a trojan. A [virustotal analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWqrN.jpg) seems to show malicious flags triggered by several vendors.

[image]
What is going on? Why does a file by Media Player Classic team contain a trojan?

Comment: sorry was still editing

Comment: Virus creators are not constrained to only using their own files. They can and do name virus files anything that they can get away with. Windows system files were a favorite in the past. It didn't mean that Microsoft was distributing viruses. It just meant the virus creators were being creative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is **not** the version of Media Player Classic installed on your computer, and indeed **is** a virus.  *Why?*

Look at the folder the executable with a virus was found in - a folder which appears to be for temporary or cached files used by Adobe Flash Player.  In terms of the actual virus, it appears to be a variant of [Win32/BitCoinMiner.G](http://www.net-security.org/malware_news.php?id=1762), which is indeed a real virus (using your computer power to mine bitcoins).

Lastly, you should be aware that the Product/Publisher/Descriptions contained in a .EXE file are set when the application is compiled.  They are in no way "official" and can easily be spoofed.

---

If you're wondering *how* that file got on your computer, it could possibly have been a [drive-by download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download).  Make sure all of your antivirus software is up to date, and if you use any third-party addons in your web browser (**especially** Java or Flash), make sure they *are always up to date* (or preferably, disabled!).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this actually explains exactly what is going on, unlike Karan's answer which just lists the obvious and does no favors to a novice user.

Answer (score 3):

1. The real MPC-HC doesn't get installed to Flash's cache folder, unless you somehow decided to place it there.
2. The real file is called **mpc-hc64.exe**
3. The real file is *not* a mere 129 KB in size (which obviously means it has a completely different SHA-256 hash).
4. Finally, the real version obviously is not launched on startup by a hidden batch file, as you yourself [seem to have discovered](https://superuser.com/questions/598218/i-would-like-to-understand-why-a-batch-file-appeared-in-flash-player-folder-for).

So what makes you assert that this really is "a file by Media Player Classic team"?

Answer (score 0):

Friend, you may have installed a fake version. I would suggest re-downloading it from an official site, and removing the current files.

(Also, if your Anti-V has a boot scan option, run it. Those nasty bitcoins sometimes place themselves in a bunch of other locations.)